# How to change each page header?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

This might seem like a silly question, but I am using VS 2010 and in the Site.Master page, there's a tag `<h1>`  which allows users to type in the title header.

E.g. [image]

In this case, the title is 'ASP.NET Application'

I'd like to have a different title in every page of my application.

How do I go about updating the title in each of my .aspx page? In the HeaderContent section of the page?

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: If you are just learning, I would encourage you to use VS2012 and start with ASP.NET MVC 4 instead.

Comment: Hi Mike, I stayed away from .NET4.5 thinking its new and might potentially have lots of bugs?
Also, I've never used MVC before (although have read up on it), so everything I do Web Application can be done in MVC? Why do you recommend that over Web Application (thinking if I should make the change now).

Comment: .NET 4.5 is fine from a stability standpoint. "Web Application" can be used for ASP.NET MVC or Web Forms. Here is [an old post from ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/24/about-technical-debates-both-in-general-and-regarding-asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-in-particular.aspx) on MVC vs Web forms. The ASP.NET team claims both are here to stay... but MVC is really the way to go... which is why they keep implementing MVC functionality into the older web forms framework.

Comment: Even at the ASP.NET conference late last year I got the impression of "Yes Web Forms is fine, trust us... but by the way, Look, it can do MVC stuff too!" made me think that MVC is what they are really focused on and Web Forms is just to placate legacy developers. That is just my perception though.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts :) very much appreciated!!! I might check out using MVC next time..hopefully not too challenging for newbie like me!

Comment: For clarification, in my previous comments, I am referring to features they had in ASP.NET MVC that they then applied to Web Forms. Even if you don't go with MVC right away, definitely upgrade to VS2012... lots of good improvements to make your life easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is different from the intent of the template. The template was constructed so that the contents of the `<h1>` would be your site logo or site name. That is why they hard-coded it into the `Site.Master` as:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>
        My ASP.NET Application
    </h1>
</div>
```

It wasn't meant to be changed per page.

If you want to change it per page, then you have a couple of options. Here is *one*.

Since you referenced the header section of the site master: lets say you want the text of the title set to the actual page title. You could do it like this:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>
        <asp:Label ID="_pageTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </h1>
</div>
```

So you replace `My ASP.NET Application` with a label so you can easily change it in the code behind.

Then, in your code behind, you have something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _pageTitle.Text = Page.Title;
    //rest of your  code
}
```

This will set the text of the label to the page title of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the Site.Master page, change the following block

```
<h1>
     My ASP.NET Application
 </h1>
```

to

```
<h1><%= Page.Title%></h1>
```

Then, in each content page, set the page title in the page directive:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplicationTest._Default" %>
```

- Note the **Title="Home Page"** attribute.

Or from code-behind:

```
Page.Title = "Home Page"
```

Comment: I'll give you a +1 even though its essentially the same answer I gave... because it is language independent and mine wasn't... even though I typically don't like code on the front-end like that (especially if extra formatting may be involved)!

Comment: Of course there are many ways to do this. I don't mind using simple inline-code, not like during those classic ASP days. Therefore I gave the solution above as the simplest way of doing it, without having to add another control and/or recompile.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is update the header in the master page and then every single web page that uses that master page will automatically have the header updated

Comment: The header in the master page has nothing to do with the `<h1>` he is referring to. I would've downvoted... but his question is a little ambiguous with his use of the term "title"... which does make you think of the header content template, but in this case he (I'm assuming) is referencing a `<h1>` in the master template.

Answer (score 0):

If looking to pass some text from each .aspx page to master page,try following. I had the similar situation and I resolve it as:

Place a `label` control with `ID="lblOnMasterPage"` on the master page.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOnMasterPage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

On code-behind file of the master page create a public property as

```
        public string LabelValue
        {
            get { return this.lblOnMasterPage.Text; }
            set { this.lblOnMasterPage.Text = value; }
        }
```

and use following code to pass the title/text you want for every page of your application..

```
((yourMasterPage)this.Master).LabelValue = "text you want to pass from each page";
```